# How can I vertically lift the Greek letter `\chi` upwards?

Tags: math-mode, equations, vertical-alignment, greek

[image]

The symbol is just `\chi`, which looks like an X letter, looks lower than it should be. Is there a way to redefine it (or combine it with an extra command) so that it is vertically lifted upwards?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}



\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
y = A \thinspace \chi
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it's Greek not cyrillic, and just like y it _should_ sit below the baseline, it is not like x which is all above the baseline.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am just using the symbol to define something else. Some people may mistake the symbol for an `X` subscript. After all, it is just my personal preference.

Comment: conversely any reader who recognises it as a chi will wonder the significance of why it is raised, you have to consider reader's understanding as well as author preference.